How to handle css for specific items in v-navigation-drawer - Vuetify 3, Vue js 3?
I have a navbar using v-navigation-drawer (Vuetify 3) . The navbar group items and group sub items are as follows
const sections = ref([
    {
        group: 'General',
        value: 'general',
        icon: generalIcon,
        items: [
          {
            icon: dashboardIcon,
            title: 'Dashboard',
            value: 'dashboard',
            path: 'dashboard',
            subItems: []
          },
          {
            icon: calendarIcon,
            title: 'Time and Date',
            value: 'time_date',
            path: 'time-date',
            subItems: []
          },
          {
            icon: downloadIcon,
            title: 'Sw Upgrade',
            value: 'sw_upgrade',
            path: 'sw-upgrade',
            subItems: []
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        group: 'System',
        value: 'system',
        icon: systemIcon,
        items: [
          {
            icon: settingIcon,
            title: 'Set-Up',
            value: 'setup',
            path: 'set-up',
            subItems: []
          },
          {
            icon: testModeIcon,
            title: 'Test Mode',
            value: 'test_mode',
            path: 'test-mode',
            subItems: []
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        group: 'Restart',
        value: 'restart',
        icon: restartIcon,
        items: []
      }
    ])

Here's the css for the group item
.group-item {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  text-transform: capitalize !important;
}

Here's the snippet for the navdrawer part of the group items
<v-navigation-drawer
  app
  :border="1"
  :elevation="0"
  location="left"
  v-model="drawer"
  :mobile-breakpoint="768"
>
  <router-link to="/dashboard">
    <v-img :width="200" aspect-ratio="16/9" class="mx-4 mt-4 mb-8" cover :src="logo"></v-img>
  </router-link>

  <v-list v-model:opened="open">
    <v-list-group
      class="mx-2"
      v-for="section in sections"
      :key="section.group"
      :value="section.group"
      @click="handleItemClick(section.group)"
    >
      <template v-slot:activator="{ props }">
        <v-list-item v-bind="props" :append-icon="null" class="group-item mb-2" :slim="true">
          <template v-slot:title>
            <p class="text-uppercase font-weight-medium">
              {{ $t(`pages.${section.value}`) }}
            </p>
          </template>
          <template v-slot:prepend>
            <v-img width="24" class="mr-2" :src="section.icon" />
          </template>
        </v-list-item>
      </template>

The background color for the group items is black.
On specific conditions (which will be handled through javascript), I want the "Restart" group to have red background. How to handle this css part?
Update:
Here are things I tried:
Adding class to the item attributes:
Eg:
{
    group: 'General',
    value: 'general',
    icon: generalIcon,
    items: [
      {
        icon: dashboardIcon,
        title: 'Dashboard',
        class: group-item,
        value: 'dashboard',
        path: 'dashboard',
        subItems: []
      },

Binding class to the group item in navbar as
 <v-list-item v-bind="props" :append-icon="null" class="mb-2" :class='section.class', :slim="true">

Now trying to bind the class based on conditions, that I can have a different class for refresh
 <v-list-item v-bind="props" :append-icon="null" class="mb-2" :class="{ section.class : groupcss}", :slim="true">

where const groupcss = ref(true)
But facing syntax error with class binding. What's the right syntax ?
